# How to fetch the records which is belongs to only one group in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to fetch the student_id which is only belongs to one collage 
expected op 
6 and 7 stud_id's so how can i do this?

```
 _id | stud_id | collage_id | university_id  | active 
-----+---------+------------+----------------+--------
   1 |       2 |          2 |              2 | t
   6 |       2 |          3 |              3 | t
   7 |       6 |          2 |              2 | t
   8 |       7 |          2 |              2 | t
   9 |       8 |          2 |              2 | t
  10 |       8 |          3 |              2 | t
```

and also if i need fetch the data which is belongs to perticular collage , i mean to use where clause ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `count(distinct collage_id)` grouping by `stud_id` in this way:

```
select   stud_id
from     tbl
group by stud_id
having   count(distinct collage_id) = 1;
```

> ```
> | stud_id |
> | ------: |
> |       6 |
> |       7 |
> ```

<kbd>*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d29aea596fa2796bcee51549d839cdc3)*</kbd>

If you want to fetch rows filtering by `collage_id`:

```
select *
from   tbl
where  collage_id = 3
and    stud_id in (select   stud_id
                   from     tbl
                   group by stud_id
                   having   count(distinct collage_id) = 1);
```

Note I've modified a bit your sample data.

> ```
> _id | stud_id | collage_id | university_id | active
> --: | ------: | ---------: | ------------: | :-----
>   8 |       7 |          3 |             2 | t
> ```

<kbd>*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ffbcdf5f2936e480d3ba6c414a2ce812)*</kbd>

Comment: yes this is working fine thank you so much, but if i wnt to use where clause to the same query then? i mean to get  data for perticular collage

Comment: Please, add it to your question.

Comment: YEs added please check;)

Comment: i tried this `select std_id from tbl where collage_id = 2 group by std_id having count(distinct collage_id) = 1`but it is returning all data i mean 2,6,7 & 8 ;(